why does pthread_cond_timedwait uses 2 locks(condlock and mutex)?
the essential steps of pthread_cond_timedwait are as follows:
1. Acquire the mutex lock (before calling pthread_cond_timedwait).
2. Acquire the cond lock.
3. Release the mutex lock.
4. Modify the cond data.
5. Release the cond lock.
6. Execute futex_wait.
7. woken up by other thread.
8. Re-acquire the cond lock.
9. Compare the cond data to determine if the current thread was woken up normally or due to a timeout, and whether it needs to wait again.
10. Modify the cond data.
11. Release the cond lock.
12. Re-acquire the mutex lock.
13. Release the mutex lock (after calling pthread_cond_timedwait).

Why the cond lock is needed, instead of using mutex lock only? That is to say:
1. Acquire the mutex lock (before calling pthread_cond_timedwait).
2. Modify the cond data.
3. Release the mutex lock.
4. Execute futex_wait.
5. woken up by other thread.
6. Re-acquire the mutex lock.
7. Compare the cond data to determine if the current thread was woken up normally or due to a timeout, and whether it needs to wait again.
8. Modify the cond data.
9. Release the mutex lock (after calling pthread_cond_timedwait).


Where did you get these steps?

@n.m.couldbeanAI I've read the source code of pthread_cond_timedwait() and I think these are the essential steps of it. While there might be minor differences in the implementation across different linux versions, I believe they wouldn't significantly affect this question.

Pthreads does not specify that there is any kind of lock inherently associated with a pthreads condition variable.  It does not specify the detailed steps presented in the question.  If some particular implementation does that, then it is for that implementation's own reasons.
However, taking it as a hypothetical that some implementation's pthread_cond_timedlock() indeed behaves as described, we can consider why that might be.  Let's suppose that it was competently programmed, without unneeded locking.  Why would it be insufficient to rely on the mutex passed to pthread_cond_timedlock() for protecting access to the CV's state?
The answer is (at least) threefold:

Some CV operations are not required to be performed under protection of a mutex.  In particular, it is not required to hold any particular mutex locked when calling pthread_cond_signal() or pthread_cond_broadcast().
If CV access requires protection by a lock, then all accesses require that protection,

Even pthread_cond_wait() and pthread_cond_timedwait() can, in principle, be called with different mutexes at different times, so long as there is no time when concurrent waits on the same CV use different mutexes.
If CV access requires protection by a lock, that can be effective only if all accesses use the same lock.

Per the specs:

These functions atomically release mutex and cause the calling thread to block on the condition variable cond; atomically here means "atomically with respect to access by another thread to the mutex and then the condition variable". That is, if another thread is able to acquire the mutex after the about-to-block thread has released it, then a subsequent call to pthread_cond_broadcast() or pthread_cond_signal() in that thread shall behave as if it were issued after the about-to-block thread has blocked.

It is plausible that ensuring conformance with that requirement would require a lock or some similar aid above and beyond the mutex.



Thanks, Join! Through the pthread's implementation, it seems that "if another thread is able to acquire the mutex after the about-to-block thread has released it......shall behave as if it were issued after the about-to-block thread has blocked" is achieved by a recorded 'futex_val' before step '5. Release the cond lock.'. and in futex_wait there will be a comparison between the saved 'futex_val' and its current value. If they're different, futex_wait will return immediately. 'futex_val' will be changed in pthread_cond_broadcast and pthread_cond_signal.
